How to Query JSON Array of unnamed objects
I have rows containing Json like: [{"Qty": 1, "Amt": 2.99},{"Qty": 3, Amt": 4.50}]
How do I get a sum of Amt per row?
Reproduction Code:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.SqlQueryResults;
CREATE TABLE dbo.SqlQueryResults(
  Id INT,
  Result nvarchar(max)
)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.SqlQueryResults (Id, Result) 
VALUES 
  (1, '[{"Qty":1, "Amt":2.99}, {"Qty":3, "Amt":4.50}]'), 
  (2, '[{"Qty":2, "Amt":7.99}, {"Qty":5, "Amt":2.50}]')

SELECT * FROM dbo.SqlQueryResults;

I am stuck around the Json Path Expression.  The documentation JSON Path Expressions (SQL Server) only shows arrays with a name "people": [{}.{}] for ex
This is the query I have at the moment:
SELECT Id, SUM(CAST( JSON_VALUE(Result,N'lax $.[].Amt') as decimal)) 
FROM SqlQueryResults
GROUP BY Id


I voted this up for your effort to provide a copy-n-paste scenario.

here is one way:
SELECT 
    id,
    sum(cast(JSON_VALUE(value, '$.Amt') as numeric(10,2))) as sum_Amt
FROM dbo.SqlQueryResults 
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(Result)
GROUP BY id 

output :



id
sum_Amt




1
7.49


2
10.49




Cross Apply OPENJSON, awesome!  Will try when back at computer

You might want to look into the WITH clause of OPENJSON.

You can try OPENJSON together with WITH. This returns casted and named columns of nested JSON.
SELECT qr.Id
      ,TheJson.*
FROM dbo.SqlQueryResults qr
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(qr.Result) 
            WITH(
                 Qty INT,
                 Amt DECIMAL(10,4)
                ) TheJson;

To solve your issue:
SELECT qr.Id
      ,SUM(TheJson.Amt) SumAmt
FROM dbo.SqlQueryResults qr
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(qr.Result) 
            WITH(Amt DECIMAL(10,4)) TheJson
GROUP BY ID;


I like this, thank you!
